# Value range for Image HSV for color extraction EMGUCV

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

In the following,

```
        Image<Hsv, Byte> hsvimg = img.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();           
        Image<Gray, Byte>[] channels = hsvimg.Split();  
        Image<Gray, Byte> imghue = channels[0];         
        Image<Gray, Byte> imgsat = channels[1];
        Image<Gray, Byte> imgval = channels[2];         

        Image<Gray, byte> huefilter = imghue.InRange(new Gray(?), new Gray(?));            
        Image<Gray, byte> satfilter = imghue.InRange(new Gray(?), new Gray(?));
        Image<Gray, byte> valfilter = imgval.InRange(new Gray(?), new Gray(?));
```

What is the range value of different channel (h, s, v) for different color extraction? Is it 0-255 or 0-128. I want to detect Orange, Black and Sky blue object for an image.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this for orange

```
 Image<Gray, byte> huefilter = 
                imghue.InRange(new Gray(Color.Orange.GetHue() - 10), 
                                     new Gray(Color.Orange.GetHue() + 10));
```

-10 and +10 is just a guess and could be broad. just play with it and see what works.

for   `satfilter` you can use `Color.Orange.GetSaturation()`

and for the third one, I'm assuming you can use `Color.Orange.GetBrightness()`

Comment: Color.Orange.GetHue() returns value from 0-255 , Color.Orange.GetSaturation() returns value from 0-1, I m little confused what img.InRange() range values require... still I can't detect the orange one

Comment: @littleBrain checkout this codefile http://code.google.com/p/howme/source/browse/trunk/PC_Client/MyRobot/CameraControl.cs?spec=svn7&r=7

Comment: Color.Orange.GetSaturation() ... is Color under System.Drawing Namespace?